# Docker compose issues

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose to add a self hosted Open Source CRM to my server.
The CRM runs fine when running without `volumes` added, when I add volumes and access the page I get an error:

```
Network Error
Could not read authentication system settings (//server_ip:8081/system/auth/). Inspect your settings or contact your IT team.

Settings:
System API URL    //server_ip:8081/system
Compose API URL   //server_ip:8081/compose
Messaging API URL //server_ip8:8081/messaging
```

My files

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: percona:8.0
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE:      corteza
      MYSQL_USER:          corteza
      MYSQL_PASSWORD:      pswd
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpswd
    healthcheck: { test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "Server_IP"], timeout: 20s, retries: 10 }
    volumes: [ "./data/db:/var/lib/mysql" ]

  server:
    image: cortezaproject/corteza-server-monolith:latest
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: [ .env ]
    environment:
      CORREDOR_API_BASE_URL_SYSTEM:    "Server_IP:80/system"
      CORREDOR_API_BASE_URL_MESSAGING: "Server_IP:80/messaging"
      CORREDOR_API_BASE_URL_COMPOSE:   "Server_IP:80/compose"
      CORREDOR_ADDR:                   "corredor:${LOCAL_DEMO_CRD_PORT}"
    depends_on: [ db, corredor ]
    ports: [ "Server_IP:${LOCAL_DEMO_API_PORT}:80" ]
    volumes: [ "./data/server:/data" ]

  corredor:
    image: cortezaproject/corteza-server-corredor:latest
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: [ .env ]
    environment:
      CORREDOR_ADDR:                   "corredor:${LOCAL_DEMO_CRD_PORT}"
    ports: [ "Server_IP:${LOCAL_DEMO_CRD_PORT}:50051" ]

  webapp:
    image: cortezaproject/corteza-webapp:latest
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on: [ server ]
    environment:
      MONOLITH_API: 1
      API_BASEURL:  "Server_IP:${LOCAL_DEMO_API_PORT}"
    ports: [ "Server_IP:${LOCAL_DEMO_SPA_PORT}:80" ]

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "81:80"
      - "444:443"
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy"
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - ./htpasswd:/etc/nginx/htpasswd
      - ./vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./custom.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  nginx-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-letsencrypt
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - ./vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

.env file

```
VERSION=2020.6

DB_DSN=corteza:rootpswd@tcp(db:3306)/corteza?collation=utf8mb4_general_ci

AUTH_JWT_SECRET=.......

LOCAL_DEMO_SPA_PORT=8080
LOCAL_DEMO_API_PORT=8081
LOCAL_DEMO_CRD_PORT=8082

# SMTP settings
SMTP_HOST=xxx
SMTP_USER=xxx
SMTP_PASS=xxx
SMTP_FROM=xxx
```

-------------------------------------------Docker Checks----------------------------------------------------

```
#docker-compose ps
 
   Name                          Command                 State                     Ports    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dockercomposefile_corredor_1   /corredor/node_modules/.bi ...   Up           server_port:8082->50051/tcp, 80/tcp
dockercomposefile_db_1         /docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld     Restarting
dockercomposefile_server_1     /corteza/bin/server serve-api    Exit 0
dockercomposefile_webapp_1     /entrypoint.sh                   Up           server_port:8080->80/tcp
nginx-letsencrypt              /bin/bash /app/entrypoint. ...   Up
nginx-proxy                    /app/docker-entrypoint.sh  ...   Restarting


docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                                  NAMES
4d38bedd37de        cortezaproject/corteza-webapp:latest            "/entrypoint.sh"         15 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes (healthy)         server_port:8080->80/tcp              dockercomposefile_webapp_1
988b56c6c097        jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion          "/bin/bash /app/entr…"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes                                                          nginx-letsencrypt
e711d5700259        jwilder/nginx-proxy                             "/app/docker-entrypo…"   15 minutes ago      Restarting (0) 44 seconds ago                                          nginx-proxy
2e174c43e361        percona:8.0                                     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   15 minutes ago      Restarting (1) 40 seconds ago                                          dockercomposefile_db_1
aa1066533c41        cortezaproject/corteza-server-corredor:latest   "/corredor/node_modu…"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes (unhealthy)       80/tcp, server_port:8082->50051/tcp   dockercomposefile_corredor_1
```

------------------------------------ Log Files ----------------------------------------

cortezaproject/corteza-server-monolith (stopped)

```
{"level":"warn","ts":1594843456.5513225,"logger":"database","caller":"db/connector.go:66","msg":"could not connect to the database","name":"default","error":"dial tcp: lookup db on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host","errorVerbose":"dial tcp: lookup db on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host\ngithub.com/titpetric/factory.(*DatabaseFactory).Get\n\t/drone/src/vendor/github.com/titpetric/factory/database.go:142\ngithub.com/cortezaproject/corteza-server/pkg/db.TryToConnect.func1\n\t/drone/src/pkg/db/connector.go:64\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1373","try":12,"dsn":"c****a:e****]@tcp(db:3306)/corteza?collation=utf8mb4_general_ci","delay":5}
Error: could not connect to database: db init for "default" timedout
Usage:
  corteza-server serve-api [flags]

Aliases:
  serve-api, serve

Flags:
  -h, --help   help for serve-api
```

jwilder/nginx-proxy (stopped)

```
nginx.1    | 2020/07/15 20:19:39 [crit] 31#31: pread() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf" failed (21: Is a directory)
nginx.1    | nginx: [crit] pread() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf" failed (21: Is a directory)
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5200
forego     | sending SIGTERM to nginx.1
forego     | sending SIGTERM to dockergen.1
forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
nginx.1    | 2020/07/15 20:20:40 [crit] 29#29: pread() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf" failed (21: Is a directory)
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5200
forego     | sending SIGTERM to nginx.1
forego     | sending SIGTERM to dockergen.1
forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
nginx.1    | 2020/07/15 20:21:41 [crit] 28#28: pread() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf" failed (21: Is a directory)
nginx.1    | nginx: [crit] pread() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf" failed (21: Is a directory)
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5200
nginx.1    | 2020/07/15 20:21:41 [crit] 35#35: pread() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf" failed (21: Is a directory)
forego     | sending SIGTERM to nginx.1
forego     | sending SIGTERM to dockergen.1
forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
nginx.1    | 2020/07/15 20:22:42 [crit] 29#29: pread() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf" failed (21: Is a directory)
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5200
forego     | sending SIGTERM to nginx.1
forego     | sending SIGTERM to dockergen.1
```

Percona (stopped)

```
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2020-07-15T20:24:52.479361Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2020-07-15T20:24:52.479490Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19-10) starting as process 1
2020-07-15T20:24:52.483199Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2020-07-15T20:24:52.483212Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2020-07-15T20:24:52.483834Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-07-15T20:24:52.484179Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19-10)  Percona Server (GPL), Release 10, Revision f446c04.
```

Nginx-Letsencrypt (Running)

```
2020/07/15 20:25:46 Received event start for container e711d5700259
2020/07/15 20:25:46 Received event die for container e711d5700259
2020/07/15 20:25:53 Received event start for container 2e174c43e361
2020/07/15 20:25:54 Received event die for container 2e174c43e361
2020/07/15 20:26:09 Debounce minTimer fired
2020/07/15 20:26:09 Contents of /app/letsencrypt_service_data did not change. Skipping notification '/app/signal_le_service'
```

dockercomposefile_webapp_1 (running)

```
{"@timestamp":"2020-07-15T20:09:32+00:00","remote_addr":"86.2.219.92","request":"GET /auth/config.js HTTP/1.1","status":200,"body_bytes_sent":152,"request_time":0.000,"http_referrer":"http://server_ip:8080/auth/login","http_user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-07-15T20:13:24+00:00","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1","request":"GET /config.js HTTP/1.1","status":200,"body_bytes_sent":152,"request_time":0.000,"http_referrer":"","http_user_agent":"Wget"}
```

dockercomposefile_corredor_1 (running)

```
{"level":30,"time":1594843405819,"name":"check","msg":"server-scripts service configured","v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1594843405820,"name":"check","output":"/tmp/corredor/bundler-dist","msg":"making bundler output directory","v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1594843405821,"name":"services.dependencies","msg":"initializing watcher","v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1594843405838,"name":"services.server-scripts","searchPaths":["/extensions/*","/corredor/usr/*","/corredor/usr"],"msg":"reloading server scripts","v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1594843405897,"name":"services.client-scripts","searchPaths":["/extensions/*","/corredor/usr/*","/corredor/usr"],"msg":"reloading client scripts","v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1594843407370,"name":"services.client-scripts","valid":19,"total":19,"msg":"processed","v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1594843410742,"name":"services.server-scripts","valid":14,"total":14,"msg":"processed","v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1594843410785,"name":"gRPC","msg":"server running at corredor:8082","v":1}
```

I have set the permissions to the files inside my /var/lib/docker/Dockercomposefile to mysql
with the exception of docker-compose.yaml and .env which are set to root.

Folder permissions also set to 777

Previously all files where set to root but still did not work

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like mysql cannot write to the data directory.

Comment: @BurakSerdar is that the data directory within docker compose? ive looked at that but am unsure what to do. I have changed the permission from 777 root to 777 mysql

Comment: The data directory is ./data/db that is mounted by the container. It cannot write to that directory.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I have changed the folder permissions to 999:999 to see if that works. I now get an error - `mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)`

Comment: 999 is not a  valid permission. It looks like the directory permission is the problem. Change the directory permission to 775 and try.

Comment: @BurakSerdar the 999 was the owner sorry, not the permissions, I have set the folders to 777 to check as they were at 755 before but no diference

Comment: We are talking about the ./data/db directory, right? If the directory permission is 775 (not 755) and the files under that are similar, then it should work.

Comment: @BurakSerdar gives me the same error, I have changed all folders/files to 775 and

Comment: you set mysql root password in DSN and user is corteza. try this 
DB_DSN=corteza:pswd@tcp(db:3306)/corteza?collation=utf8mb4_general_ci